# Remove all elements from the dictionary whose key is an element of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do you remove all elements from the dictionary whose key is a element of a list?

Comment: Is this homework?  Can you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 11):

[**Note**: This is not direct answer but given earlier speculation that the question looks like homework. I wanted to provide help that will help solving the problem while learning from it]

**Decompose your problem which is**:

1. How to get a element from a list
2. How to delete a key:value in dictionary

Further help:

> How do get all element of a list on python?

For loop works on all sequences and list is a sequence.

```
for key in sequence: print key
```

> How do you delete a element in dictionary?

use the del(key) method.

- http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html

**You should be able to combine the two tasks.**

Comment: You did not answer the question. You may have pointed him in the right direction, but not everyone wants to go on a quest for knowledge while trying to quickly get something done at work.

Comment: @Will: I understand. I was one of the early one to answer this question. And from conversation, it looked like this was a homework problem. At Stackoverflow, we dissuade answering the question unless some attempts has been shown. I thought, I have provided a good direction that will hold him in good stead rather than provide for cut n paste solution. I hope the context helps.

Answer (score 11):

```
for key in list_:
    if key in dict_:
        del dict_[key]
```

Comment: nice, i didnt know you could do this.  thought you had to use has_key.  thanks!  btw, del dict_[k] should probably be del dict_[key], right?

Comment: @blackkettle: in Python 3 `key in dict_` is actually the only way to check if a dict has some given key -- the `has_key()` method has been dropped.

Comment: @Sven Marnach I was not aware of that either! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 7):

```
map(dictionary.__delitem__, lst)
```

Comment: Only useful if all of lst is in dictionary - otherwise you'll get a KeyError somewhere along the way.  Try: `map(dictionary.__delitem__, filter(dictionary.__contains__, lst))`  (Although in truth, I am not a big fan of using `map` or list comps as stand-ins for normal for loops.)

Comment: @Paul: I believe that gnibbler intended the answer as more or less correct yet mostly inappropriate for homework… :)

Comment: Yes, I've done the same myself on other homework-y questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
newdict = dict(
    (key, value) 
    for key, value in olddict.iteritems() 
    if key not in set(list_of_keys)
)
```

---

Later (like in late 2012):

```
keys = set(list_of_keys)
newdict =  dict(
    (key, value) 
    for key, value in olddict.iteritems() 
    if key not in keys
)
```

Or if you use a 2.7+ python dictionary comprehension:

```
keys = set(list_of_keys)
newdict =  {
    key: value
    for key, value in olddict.iteritems() 
    if key not in keys
}
```

Or maybe even a python 2.7 dictionary comprehension plus a set intersection on the keys:

```
required_keys = set(olddict.keys()) - set(list_of_keys)
return {key: olddict[key] for key in required_keys}
```

---

Oh yeah, the problem might well have been that I had the condition reversed for calculating the keys required.

Comment: You should move `set(list_of_keys)` outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4}
l = ['zero', 'two', 'four', 'five']
for k in frozenset(l) & frozenset(d):
    del d[k]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in lst:
    if i in d.keys():
        del(d[i])
```

Comment: This will construct a list or iterator for `d.keys()` on every step. You only need to do `if i in d:` this will be shorter and much efficient way of doing this, and there is already the answer like this.

Answer (score -2):

I know nothing about Python, but I guess you can traverse a list and remove entries by key from the dictionary?